# Is it wrong/strange to use the simple past tense version of "who the hell [does this]?"

Tags: tense, phrase-usage, past-tense

For example:

> Who the hell eats instant noodles for breakfast?

Is it incorrect/weird to say:

> Who the hell ate instant noodles for breakfast?

(Say, if you're writing in first-person past-tense narrative?)

If so, what's a better alternative?

Comment: The words ***the hell*** are syntactically irrelevant to the issue being asked about here, and imho should be deleted. *(That* would be a "better alternative" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "the hell X", if X is a verb, doesn't affect the decision of X's tense.

Simple present is often used to express habitual activities (i.e. you normally do X), in addition to narration.

> Who the hell eats instant noodles for breakfast?

Someone might not have actually eaten any noodles (but we might be talking about someone we are watching eating noodles).

> Who the hell ate instant noodles for breakfast?

This means someone ate some noodles yesterday.

Comment: I think the last example needs to be more specific as to the past event. "Who the hell ate *my/the* instant noodles?" You can't really say "for breakfast" unless the time frame indicates that, since the action wasn't witnessed.

Comment: It's possible, but a bit unusual, for "eating instant noodles for breakfast" as opposed to say, lunch or a snack, to be a significant event to someone in and of itself.

Comment: @user3169 yes you can: Lizzy yelled "Who the hell ate instant noodles for breakfast?" as she threw the empty pot in the dishwasher before recycling.  Vs Lizzy gives Alice a strange look "You what? Who the hell eats instant noodles for breakfast?"  these are obviously both very casual language examples